# Multiple feature collections in single Geojson OL3

Tags: geojson, openlayers-3

I use geojson files to display layers on maps with openlayers3. Each geojson file contains one feature collection representing a layer. What  I would like to do is to gather those geojson files in single one. So, I should have several feature collections in single geojson. Is it possible to do that and can I read this kind of geojson in openlayers3? Thank you very much for you help.
Regards.

Comment: But do you want to do this definitely? I mean, do you want to join these files into one in your directory?